# macos clipboard is parsing "/n" as "⏎"

Tags: macos, unicode, clipboard

So I am copying some raw string from chrome inspect tab which after pasting, the result seems to be altered: the "/n" has been replaced with unicode symbol "⏎".

My question is, is clipboard supposed to parse and interprete? why?

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [eagerly evaluating](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/devtools#eagerevaluation) expressions, Chrome puts the entire output on one line. Hit enter to (uneagerly) evaluate the expression for real  to get the actual value without ⏎s.